# Can't import JSON with Arrays to Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I usually make a copy of a Node, with 'Export JSON', in the 3 dots menu at the top right.
[image]

Then I go to another path and Import the same JSON.

A few days ago, I remember that I could do it without problems.

Now, when I try to Import the JSON from one Node to another Node, it says that it contains "[" "]" and it can't import because of that.

I know that Firebase transforms arrays into Objects with number keys like
{0: "value", 1: "value"}.... but when I export the database, it gives me a Json with Arrays... that the same Firebase don't accept when I try to import in another part of the database.

How could I transform this JSON with arrays to be accepted by Firebase again?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to transform your data like this:

```
"productos" {
    "productoUid" : {
       "cor" : "preto",
       "modelo" : "SJ53SA" ,
       "tamanho" : "PP",
       "tipo" : "remover",
       //this is same uid as productoUid
       "uid" : SJ54SApretoM"
    }, 
    "productoUid2": {/* product item*/}, ....
}
```

This way you'll be able to iterate through all children of **productos** node and add them to list. This solution is easier to maintain the keeping the data in an array.

[Here](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html) and [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data) you can read why in Firebase real-time database storing data in an array is bad practice.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I need to keep the logic of the JSON. What I needed was to transform the array in to a object, with the same structure, but convert it to the firebase schema {0: 'a', 1: 'b', .... etc }

Comment: I did it after you say it. The result: "Valid JSON". With the arrays inside the JSON